# pgfmathsetlengthmacro with width("...") in multilanguage document

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a code in which `tikz` `width("")` function/macro is used to get the length of a string and stored it into a length variable using `pgfmathsetlengthmacro`.

It seems that the length variable that is set in english environment will be usable only in english environment for either set the matrix width or just being printed. Similarly for the second language. Even assigning the content of `\ll` in the code below to a tex length variable to print it in a \textenglish{...} macro is failing.

Is there a way to be able to use that length in another language environment than the one in which it was set (by `width("")`)? My document's main language is a foreign one and matrix's contain text in both languages and most of the time english text is the longest, hence it must be used to set the column width.

For the flexibility of `matrix`'s in `tikz` I don't want to use `NiceTabular`. In which case there is no need to determine manually the width of the columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\newlength{\slw}\setlength{\slw}{160mm}
\newlength{\slh}\setlength{\slh}{90mm}
\geometry{verbose,papersize={\slw,\slh}}

\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSerifDevanagari}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,math}

  \tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                      nodes in empty cells,matrix anchor=#1,
                      every outer matrix/.append style={
                        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={outer sep=0pt},
                      text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
  }

\newlength{\texlength}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{english} 
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ll}{ width("iiiiii") } 
      \setlength\texlength{\ll}
      \matrix at (0,0) [allmatrix={north}, draw,
        nodes={text width=7*\texlength}] (eng)
        {
          \ll \\           % here \ll is printed normally
          \the\texlength \\  % 
        };
    \end{english}
    
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ls}{ width("लघु") } 
    \matrix at (5,0) [allmatrix={north}, draw,
      nodes={text width=10*\ls}] (sam) %here \ll instead of \ls will not work
      {  संस्कृतं मधुरम् अस्ति। \ll \\         % here \ll is not printed
        \eng{text in english \ll} \\ 
        \eng{ \the\texlength } \\ };% This fails as it shows "0.0 pt"
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is rather a scoping issue. If you set the length inside the `english` environment, you are probably setting `\ll` only inside the scope.

Comment: Maybe somebody will scold me for suggesting this, but you could add `\ExplSyntaxOn \NewDocumentCommand { \gsetlength } { mm } { \skip_gset:Nn #1 { #2 } } \ExplSyntaxOff` and this way define a command `\gsetlength` that sets the length globally. This way, you can set the length inside the scope and still use it outside of it. Handle with care and use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

With LaTeX, lengths assignments are local, limited to the current group and `\begin{english}...\end{english}` forms a group.

The simplest is to make `\texlength` global, just after its setting:

```tex
\setlength{\texlength}{\ll}
\global\texlength=\texlength
```

You can also set `\textlength` inside a group which is common to all its  uses, for example just after `\begin{frame}`:

```tex
\settowidth{\texlength}{\textlang{english}{iiiiii}}
```

Full code, with the second solution:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\newlength{\slw}\setlength{\slw}{160mm}
\newlength{\slh}\setlength{\slh}{90mm}
\geometry{verbose,papersize={\slw,\slh}}

\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSerifDevanagari}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,math}

  \tikzset{
  allmatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                      nodes in empty cells,matrix anchor=#1,
                      every outer matrix/.append style={
                        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
                      row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                      ampersand replacement=\&, nodes={outer sep=0pt},
                      text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
  }

\newlength{\texlength}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \settowidth{\texlength}{\textlang{english}{iiiiii}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{english}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ll}{ width("iiiiii") }
      \matrix at (0,0) [allmatrix={north}, draw,
        nodes={text width=7*\texlength}] (eng)
        {
          Inside \texttt{english} env.\\
          \ll                 % here \ll is printed normally
          {\footnotesize~\texttt{\textbackslash ll}}\\
          \the\texlength      % \texlength and \ll are equal
          {\footnotesize~\texttt{\textbackslash texlength}}\\
        };
    \end{english}

    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ls}{ width("लघु") }
    \matrix at (5,0) [allmatrix={north}, draw,
      nodes={text width=10*\ls}] (sam)
      { \eng{Outside \texttt{english} env.}\\
        संस्कृतं मधुरम् अस्ति। \\
        \eng{text in english} \\
        \eng{ \ll             % \ll is undefined here (shows nothing)
          {\footnotesize~\texttt{\textbackslash ll} (undefined here)}
        } \\
        \eng{ \the\texlength  % \texlength is defined here (shows "15.48001pt")
          {\footnotesize~\texttt{\textbackslash texlength}}
        } \\ };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: set width in a common group]

Comment: `\ll` was not declared anywhere in your code, you meant `\ls`?

Comment: @user1850133 Sorry, I was focused on `\texlength`, not `\ll`. Fixed. Should be clearer now. Thanks.